# MutableState callback in non-Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `MutableState` -- how to create a callback that will be called each time its value changes in a non-Composable function?

Comment: Do you wish to call non-Composable function every time state changes, right? And how are these related? Are they sibling functions or non-Composable is inside Composable function?

Comment: @Thracian Yes, I wish to call the non-Composable function on every change. This function resides in my ViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SnapshotFlow is what you might need. It also lets you filter, map use any Flow operator that you might need too.

```
val stateQuery by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow {
        stateQuery
    }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .onEach { query ->
            viewModel.search(query)
        }
        .launchIn(this)
}
```

Comment: Actually, `snapshotFlow`'s docs state that "If the result of block is not equal to the previous result, the flow will emit that new result. (This behavior is similar to that of Flow.distinctUntilChanged.)", so it seems like `distinctUntilChanged()` is redundant here